# Next js console error on Next.js-14 (app router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, next.js, next.js14

In my next.js (14 app router) project, I am getting a console Warning.

[image]

If I comment on the TopNav component, it shows a similar error for another component, even if I comment out all the code from RootLayout and print h1 tag, it still shows the error.

[image]

Opening the project on chrome incognito window shows me the error

[image]

How Can I solve the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off your grammarly chrome extension and it will solve the issue.

Comment: No, Still I am getting same warning even after remove grammarly extension, even after creating new project

Comment: Try disabling few more extensions, some extensions trouble us, you need to figure out which one. Grammarly in some cases metamask or may be nay other

Answer (score 0):

```
suppressHydrationWarning={true}
```

Add this in the body tag in root layout.jsx

```
<body className={manrope.className} suppressHydrationWarning={true} >
```